How do I prevent app.db from being persisted between docker container restarts?
I created an ASP.NET Core MVC application, and checked the "enable container support". This gives me 5 ways to launch the application: http, https, IIS Express, Container (dockerfile), WSL.
I assumed that when using the "Container (dockerfile)" launch option, none of the data in the container would get persisted, but that doesn't seem to be the case. My "app.db" file is hanging on to the test users that I created. I tried cleaning the solution, I tried stopping and removing the container, I tired removing the images and builds from the "docker desktop" tool on Windows and none of it works.
I know I am missing something very basic, but I have been at it for a few evenings and I am stuck.
Here are files that I think might be relevant.
Dockerfile
# See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

# This stage is used when running from VS in fast mode (Default for Debug configuration)
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081


# This stage is used to build the service project
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DockerTest2/DockerTest2.csproj", "DockerTest2/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./DockerTest2/DockerTest2.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/DockerTest2"
RUN dotnet build "./DockerTest2.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

# This stage is used to publish the service project to be copied to the final stage
FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./DockerTest2.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

# This stage is used in production or when running from VS in regular mode (Default when not using the Debug configuration)
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerTest2.dll"]

.dockerignore
**/.classpath
**/.dockerignore
**/.env
**/.git
**/.gitignore
**/.project
**/.settings
**/.toolstarget
**/.vs
**/.vscode
**/*.*proj.user
**/*.dbmdl
**/*.jfm
**/azds.yaml
**/bin
**/charts
**/docker-compose*
**/Dockerfile*
**/node_modules
**/npm-debug.log
**/obj
**/secrets.dev.yaml
**/values.dev.yaml
LICENSE
README.md
!**/.gitignore
!.git/HEAD
!.git/config
!.git/packed-refs
!.git/refs/heads/**
**/app.db           <<<<<<< added by me
**/app.db-shm
**/app.db-wal

launchSettings.json
{
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5106"
    },
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7201;http://localhost:5106"
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Container (Dockerfile)": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS": "8081",
        "ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS": "8080"
      },
      "publishAllPorts": true,
      "useSSL": true
    },
    "WSL": {
      "commandName": "WSL2",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "https://localhost:7201",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "https://localhost:7201;http://localhost:5106"
      },
      "distributionName": ""
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:53919",
      "sslPort": 44308
    }
  }
}


Please ensure you are not select Debug mode. In debug mode, VS2022 will mount your project folder in order to accelerate debug process and support hot reload. Please use Release mode for sure.

That does seem to work, but I don't want to lose debugging capabilities. I am trying to specifically troubleshoot some startup issues I am having.
